# Entity Framework Keys List

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I'm trying to use Entity Framework in Code First mode to try and store some objects, and I'm having trouble with key generation (or rather I don't want to have to alter my existing objects to insert keys). Here is an example of the problem I am having:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApplication2
{
public class AClass
{
    [Key]
    public int id { get; set; }
    public List<SubClass> l;
};

public class SubClass
{
    public string a;
    public string b;
};

public class ADbContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<AClass> dbset { get; set; }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        ADbContext db = new ADbContext();

        AClass a = new AClass();

        a.id = 1;
        a.l = new List<SubClass>();

        SubClass sc=new SubClass();

        sc.a = "Hello";
        sc.b = "World";

        a.l.Add(sc);

        SubClass sca = new SubClass();

        sca.a = "Stack";
        sca.b = "Overflow";

        a.l.Add(sca);

        db.dbset.Add(a);
        db.SaveChanges();
    }
}
}
```

If you run this program, then it errors saying that the object SubClass has no primary key. Now if I was writing a program by hand without using Entity Framework to store these objects in a database, what I would do is have tables like:

```
AClass:
id int public key

SubClass:
AClass_id int foreign key references AClass(id),
postition_in_list_id int, 
a string,
b string,
primary key (AClass_id,position_in_list_id)
```

And I'd say for AClass with id 1 I'd have SubClass (1,1), (1,2), (1,3) if you see what I mean.

Is there any way to get Entity Framework to do this, or do I have to add arbitrary IDs to SubClass?

SubClass is never stored in the database, except as a part of AClass.

Comment: As a suggestion, use a `using` block with `dbcontext` to dispose of it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this out:

```
public class SubClass
{
    [ForeignKey("AClass")]
    [Key]
    public int AClassId {get; set;}

    public string a;
    public string b;
}
```